# How to assign upper limit to an Application Pool in IIS 7.x

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, application-pool

I want to assign exact upper limit to an Application Pool in IIS 7.x

The processModel Element allows me to assign the limit but in percentage. I want to do in MBs/GBs to better manage my resources across deployed applications.

Moreover I want to do so at a centralized placed and not in Web.config of each application.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart describes various sets of sample code and how to control the memory settings.  e.g.:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='KabeerPool'].recycling.periodicRestart.privateMemory.[value=4761]" /commit:apphost
```

You can set the memory limits in KBs.

You could set the top level defaults that all new pools would inherit, but once they exist (or if you want different ones) you would have to be interacting with each of their web.configs (although it is reasonably simple to do so programmatically once you're already doing things via .NET as opposed to through the GUI)